Can the value in an R promise itself be a promise
I understand the basics of R promises. A promise contains three pieces of information: (env, expr, [val]) (with val only being present after the promise has been forced).
I want to check if the following claim/reasoning about promises is correct:

the val in a promise cannot itself be an object of type promise

Reasoning:

val is the result of evaluating expr in env
no expression evaluates to an object of type promise

(2.) should be true because promises are not self evaluating (eg. promise (env, expr, val) evaluates to val), while other R objects are self-evaluating (eg. 5 evaluates to 5).

Does it count when a promise (as an argument to a function) is itself a function, which then has arguments which are promises?

I need an example to know exactly what you mean. It seems like you mean: f is bound to a promise containing a function, g is bound to a function, and g(f,x) internally calls f(x). That wouldn't create a promise containing a promise.

There are two versions of your question:

Can I write pure R code that makes a promise contain a promise?
Can I write a package containing C code that contains a function in which a promise contains a promise?

I think you're right that the answer to question 1 is "no", but I wouldn't make a bet either way on question 2.  C code can do things that are against the rules, but R keeps getting better at detecting rule violations. So I don't know which way this one goes currently.
